# Eigen: coefficient-wise pow with small integer exponent slow

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization, eigen, pow

In Eigen,with

```
ArrayXXf a;
a = ArrayXXf::Random(1000, 10000);
```

doing

```
a = a.pow(4);
```

takes ~500ms on my pc, whereas doing

```
a = a.square().square();
```

takes only about 5ms. I'm compiling with a recent GCC in release.

Is this the expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong? I would expect, that at least for small integer (say < 20, if not using a cost function), an overload should exist that catches such cases.

Comment: You can build yourself a custom binary functor which calls `__builtin_powi` (on gcc/clang)

Comment: @chtz while it's nice on the first glance, it's as you said not portable. Especially if one wants to use the Intel compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C++17 `if constexpr` this could be possible, but otherwise it's not. So currently, `a.pow(x)` is equivalent to calling `std::pow(a[i],x)` for each `i`.

Comment: We could theoretically provide a `.pow<4>()` function (maybe with a different name)

Comment: @chtz that would be a really nice feature! It's a more or less frequent use case and the performance gain is huge.

Answer (score 1):

After a whole day of debugging I realized this was the bottleneck in my code. [On the documentation it says that there is no SIMD for `a.pow()`.](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html) For whatever reason, actually on my machine it appears `a * a * a * a` is faster for a 300 x 50 Eigen::ArrayXXd.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
    Eigen::ArrayXXd m = Eigen::ArrayXd::LinSpaced(300 * 50, 0, 300 * 50 - 1).reshaped(300, 50);

    {
        decltype(m) result; // prevent loop from being eliminated
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            result = m.square().square();
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Per run(microsecond)=" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() / 100000.0 << std::endl;
    }

    {
        decltype(m) result; // prevent loop from being eliminated
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            result = m * m * m * m;
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Per run(microsecond)=" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() / 100000.0 << std::endl;
    }

    {
        decltype(m) result; // prevent loop from being eliminated
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            result = m.pow(4);
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Per run(microsecond)=" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() / 10000.0 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
```

```
m.square().square();
Per run(microsecond)=17.9101

m * m * m * m;
Per run(microsecond)=10.3267

m.pow(4);
Per run(microsecond)=431.636
```